# SBJson *parser hey i am getting redline under *parser how should i use SBJson parsing in objective c?

Tags: mysql, objective-c

I am getting a red line under SBJson *parser now i don't know how to remove this error. Is there some kind of library I should install or what should I do to remove this error? I am stuck in json parsing in objective C.

```
SBJSON *parser=[[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/jsontest1.php"]];


NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
{
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [status objectForKey:@"text"],

          [[status objectForKey:@"user"]objectForKey:@"screen_name"]);
}
```

Comment: Red line - what a nice error description. What does the error message say? By the way, the error is obvious - if you can't find it, just start with some easier excercises.

Comment: Your first line should be: `SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];`. The variables type should match the type of object you are assigning to it.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should stop doing synchronous requests. They block the main thread and your app seems unresponsible. Secondly, unless you have a very good reason to use SBJSON (as targeting iOS < 5), you should stick with NSJSONSerialization:

```
NSError *err = nil;
NSArray *statuses = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&err];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add files for JSON parsing into your project from [here](http://superloopy.io/json-framework/).

Include proper .h file into your code.